# Spurious trampoline when calling function from DLL

Tags: visual-c++, dll, portable-executable

I have a simple console application:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void foo();

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

which calls a function from DLL:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void foo() {
    printf("Hello from foo\n");
}
```

When I step into `foo()` call in Disassembly window (Debug -> Windows -> Disassembly)

[image]

I can see that instead of jumping directly to implementation of `foo()` in DLL it goes through intermediate dummy trampoline which is also located in DLL:

[image]

I haven't found any information about such trampoline in MSDN documentation. Perhaps anyone knows why it exists? I'm using the latest Visual Studio Community for compilation.

PS: Interestingly enough, the trampoline is present only in Debug build and disappears in Release. It's also not present when compiling code with Cygwin or Msys.

Comment: If you look closely at the DLL, you'll see that it's not just exported functions that have a trampoline. **All** functions are called through trampolines, because you enabled [incremental linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/incremental-link-incrementally?view=msvc-170) when building in Debug mode. "May contain jump thunks to handle relocation of functions to new addresses."

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks, Raymond, I wasn't expecting to hear from you! Your comment is a complete answer to my question.